# Why don't they teach Fundamental Theorem of Algebra in High School?

Tags: soft-question, polynomials, education

I am currently in AP Calculus BC and one more year to go, I have heard about Fundamental Theorem of Algebra several times, and with the resources that is out there today I tried to search and study myself.  (Also noticed there are some inconsistencies in the versions of explanation about this theorem).  But I still wonder why they don't teach this in High School in the USA?  Am I wrong?  Or do they teach this in other countries?

Comment: Off-topic - not a question about Mathematics.

Comment: I do believe that they teach it in some US schools. Generally speaking, though, it isn't really useful for high schoolers to know, insofar as helping them build up technical skill and standard proficiency. It's more something you'd use for a proof.

Comment: We learn complex numbers, polynomials then can they at least give some exposure to students who are mathematically inclined

Comment: HWinslow- Did you really learned the proof, see my answer for further information

Comment: @Victor Why can't there be a simpler way to explain high school students (I know you keep pointing me to the book that assumes advanced knowledge - your point I have to know Topology?)

Comment: It really is the basic requirement to proof it, if you are able to find a simplier proof and you answer your own question, i give you upvote

Comment: This sounds like more of a complaint than a legitimate question.

Comment: @HWinslow: You might find the following worth looking at: 
*Appendix: Cauchy's proof that every equation has a root* on pp. 577-581 of **Advanced Course in Algebra** by Webster Wells (1904) http://books.google.com/books/reader?id=aOM5AAAAMAAJ

Answer (score 2):

You may need complex analysis or topology to prove it,so this is for advanced undergraduate(junior, senior) , see http://books.google.com/books?id=g0KHD7EIl4cC&printsec=frontcover&dq=fundamental+theorem+of+algebra&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ASNpT-O1B4eMgwfJn4ydCQ&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=fundamental%20theorem%20of%20algebra&f=false

Comment: Actually, there's a proof that uses only elementary analysis. See, for example, Volume 1 of Mathematical Analysis by Zorich, p 283-284.